# properly queuing different ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, queue

I see a lot of solutions to queue ajax requests but I am trying to understand how to implement one for this case. Should it be a push and shift queue?:

```
var urlList = ['urlA', 'urlB', 'urlC', ...];

function initSession() {
    for (var i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
        getResponse(urlList[i]); // this is what I would like to queue.
    }
}

function getResponse(theURL) {
    steps.shuffleLetters({
        "text": messages[mesInd]
    });
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: theURL,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                steps.shuffleLetters({
                    "text": data
                });
            }, 1000);
            mesInd = mesInd + 1;
        },
        error: function(data) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                steps.shuffleLetters({
                    "text": "Click Again!"
                });
            }, 1000);
            mesInd = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `$.ajax` is returning a promise. I think that's the way to go.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze the returned object acts like a `Promise` but isn't one: _"The jqXHR objects returned by `$.ajax()` as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise"_

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the hint. It's a bit nitpicking :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by removing the for loop and call the next url after the success of the current request

Check the code below:

```
var urlList = ['urlA','urlB','urlC',...];
var length = urlList.length;
var currentRequest = 0;
getResponse(urlList[currentRequest]);


function getResponse(theURL){
 steps.shuffleLetters({"text": messages[mesInd]});
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: theURL,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
             setTimeout(function(){steps.shuffleLetters({"text": data});}, 1000);
             //Here you will call the next request 
             currentRequest +=1;
             if(currentRequest < length)
             {
                 getResponse(urlList[currentRequest]);
             }

             mesInd = mesInd+1;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            setTimeout(function(){steps.shuffleLetters({"text": "Click Again!"});}, 1000);
            mesInd = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks @Amr-Labib for spotting it out. My bad! Still even that way when the requests are made  one after the other, I cannot get queued responses

Comment: What do you mean by queued response ... the code above will guarantee that every request is called after the one before it is finished ...